# Remove duplicates from union in SQL Views (Toad)

Tags: sql, r, union, toad, rbind

This is a translation of R to SQL. My view is a union of two views. I then need to remove duplicates from 2 columns.

`DQC` is the union of the two views, `DEF` and `DCF`. DEF and DCF have the same 8 columns in the same order.

I've tried using a CTE like

```
CREATE VIEW DQC_FINAL AS (
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT 
RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM, CODE), *
FROM DQC
)
SELECT ITEM, CODE
FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1);
```

I'm not sure if this is the best option. I'm just trying to remove any duplicates in the column ITEM and CODE. UNION should have done it but I'm not getting the right output.

```
CREATE VIEW DQC AS
SELECT * 
FROM DEF
UNION
SELECT *
FROM DCF;
```

This output is like a UNION ALL for some reason. The record count of DEF + DCF = the record count of DQC. Here is the correctly functioning R code:

```
DQC <- rbind(DEF,DCF)
DQC <- DQC[!duplicated(DQC$ITEM, DQC$CODE),]
```

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps Distinct?  Or Group by?  Or use a `where not exists` clause in the union?

Comment: @avery_larry Can I use SELECT DISTINCT within each SELECT statement to relate the columns of the same name from the two views? I tried this to a certain extent but also got duplicate column errors. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have primary keys in *DEF* or *DCF*? Since all database tables are recommended to have this key, using `*` will select them and hence rows between the two sets do not duplicate. Carefully check uniqueness between the two tables. Even better post sample data so we can see or database table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` eliminates duplicates between the two views across *all* columns. There are several reasons that could cause the duplicates on `(ITEM, CODE)`:

1. either the records where this tuple of columns is duplicated have different values in the other columns; since these records are not *true* duplicates, `UNION` does not eliminate them. In this case, your solution with the CTE is the correct approach.
2. or one of the views (maybe both), already contains duplicates (whether true or partial). `UNION` does not removes the duplicates (even if they are true duplicates), them since they do not spread across the two queries.

In both cases, as an optimization, you could possibly skip the intermediate view by deduplicating directly the result of the `UNION` query. If there are true duplicates in the views, then you can simply use `SELECT DISTINCT` on each of the `UNION`ed queries. Else if you are dealing with partial duplicates, then you can wrap the entire `UNION` queries in a CTE and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to remove duplicates, as shown in your existing code.

A final thought: since you noticed that `UNION` actually does not remove any record, you would better use `UNION ALL` instead: this means less work for your RDBMS, and will make the queries that address the final view more efficient.

Comment: Could you show a brief example assuming DQC has used UNION ALL? I'm trying to put this current problem into a new view. I keep getting an error that FROM is in an unexpected place. And to be clear, I want all columns in the result.